# OLAP Approach for Backend redshift connection

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api, olap

We have a system where we do some aggregations in Redshift based on some conditions. We aggregate this data with complex joins which usually takes about 10-15 minutes to complete. We then show this aggregated data on Tableau to generate our reports. 
Lately, we are getting many changes regarding adding a new dimension ( which usually requires join with a new table) or get data on some more specific filter. To entertain these requests we have to change our queries everytime for each of our subprocesses. 
I went through OLAP a little bit. I just want to know if it would be better in our use case or is there any better way to design our system to entertain such adhoc requests which does not require developer to change things everytime.

Thanks for the suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would work, rather it **should** work. Efficiency is the key here. There are few things which you need to strictly monitor to make sure your system (Redshift + Tableau) remains up and running.

> Prefer Extract over Live Connection (in Tableau)

Live connection would query the system everytime someone changes the filter or refreshes the report. Since you said the dataset is large and queries are complex, prefer creating an extract. This'll make sure data is available upfront whenever someone access your dashboard .Do not forget to schedule the extract refresh, other wise the data will be stale forever.

> Write efficient queries

OLAP systems are expected to query a large dataset. Make sure you write efficient queries. It's always better to first get a small dataset and join them rather than bringing everything in the memory and then joining / using `where` clause to filter the result.

A query like `(select foo from table1 where ... )a left join (select bar from table2 where)` might be the key at times where you only take out small and relevant data and then join.

> Do not query infinite data.

Since this is analytical and not transactional data, have an upper bound on the data that Tableau will refresh. Historical data has an importance, but not from the time of inception of your product. Analysing the data for the past 3, 6 or 9 months can be the key rather than querying the universal dataset.

> Create aggregates and let Tableau query that table, not the raw tables

Suppose you're analysing user traits. Rather than querying a raw table that captures 100 records per user per day, design a table which has just one (or two) entries per user  per day and introduce a column - `count` which'll tell you the number of times the event has been triggered. By doing this, you'll be querying sufficiently smaller dataset but will be logically equivalent to what you were doing earlier.

As mentioned by [**Mr Prashant Momaya**](https://www.linkedin.com/in/prashantmomaya/%20Prashant%20Momaya),

```
"While dealing with extracts,your storage requires (size)^2 of space if your dashboard refers to a data of size - **size**"
```

Be very cautious with whatever design you implement and do not forget to consider the most important factor - scalability

Comment: Hey, I am already following Extract format in Tableau and also writing efficient queries too. Can you provide me some reference on OLAP which satisfies my  use case ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem and we tackled it by writing SQL generators in Python. If the definition of the metric is the same (like `count(*)`) but you have varying dimensions and filters you can declare it as JSON and write a generator that will produce the SQL. Example with pageviews:

```
{
    metric: "unique pageviews"
   ,definition: "count(distinct cookie_id)"
   ,source: "public.pageviews"
   ,tscol: "timestamp"
   ,dimensions: [
        ['day']
       ,['day','country']
}
```

can be relatively easy translated to 2 scripts - this:

```
 drop table metrics_daily.pageviews;
 create table metrics_daily.pageviews as
 select 
  date_trunc('day',"timestamp") as date
 ,count(distinct cookie_id) as "unique_pageviews"
 from public.pageviews
 group by 1;
```

and this:

```
 drop table metrics_daily.pageviews_by_country;
 create table metrics_daily.pageviews_by_country as
 select 
  date_trunc('day',"timestamp") as date
 ,country
 ,count(distinct cookie_id) as "unique_pageviews"
 from public.pageviews
 group by 1,2;
```

the amount of complexity of a generator required to produce such sql from such config is quite low but in increases exponentially as you need to add new joins etc. It's much better to keep your dimensions in the encoded form and just use a single wide table as aggregation source, or produce views for every join you might need and use them as sources.